# Is there any use for creating an empty object? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to learn Objective-C on my own, and the website I'm using is talking about Empty Objects.

It states `"since creating an empty object isn’t that useful, most classes implement more specific init methods that you can send to the result of alloc to create objects with data, like the initWithString: message for creating a copy of a string:"`

it isn't **that** useful, which tells me, there may be some uses for it.

Are there any? is there a scenario in which an empty object would be what someone needs?

To make this less of a discussion, I'll ask it relation to the objective-C language (I imagine different languages, different reasons).

Comment: It all depends on the class.

Comment: Perhaps something like a form model that starts empty but fills in later.  There's also a situation where an object might implement functions but not implement any actual state.  An example might be a networking adaptor.  Not sure if that's what you mean, or a purely empty object that only exists as an instance of itself and carries no individual functionality or state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in that statement is that you can create an "empty object" with [MyClass alloc] and then use the init statement to initialize them. Is a common practice in general in Objective-C.
One example is the one you have in that sentence

```
[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"My Test String"]
```

Other example could be creating a UIView:

```
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRect(0,0,100,100)];
```

Whit that you create an empty uiview and then initialize it with the frame (0,0,100,100).

Comment: ooooh i see, that actually makes so much more sense. The website didn't expand on it so i was confused. I didn't look at it that way at all. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*As a heads-up, empty objects can be used in any programming language and are in no way tied to Objective-C. However, I understand why you tagged it Obj-C, because you want an Obj-C - specific answer.
Also, I think you are misunderstanding the term "empty object" (or the website is somewhat flaky in describing what they really mean.) I think that you assume that an empty object is just an object without any methods or properties, which is not the case. By empty object the author probably just means that no properties are set in the initializer.*

More often than not, what the website claims is merely a convenience thing. By specifying an explicit initializer you almost force the user of the class to use the dedicated initializer.

Demonstration: Let's assume we have a class called house:

```
@interface House : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Door *door; 

-(id)initWithDoor: (Door* )door;

@end
```

Because the house is **composed** of a door (a house wouldn't make any sense without a door), you can almost *force* users of this class to initialize the House object with a door like this:

```
Door *door = [[Door alloc] init];
House *house = [[House alloc] initWithDoor: door];
```

The alternative way of doing it, is by creating an "empty object", i.e. just calling `init` without using the dedicated initializer and assigning the door afterwards like so:

```
Door *door = [[Door alloc] init];
House *house = [[House alloc] init];
[house setDoor: door];
```

Developers that were not involved in designing this class may not however know that the door is an important part of the House and not assign it at all, which may cause unexpected behaviour. Therefore it is more or less convenient to see that there is a dedicated initializer.

Generally you would have a combination of both. If the house needs to be composed of a door for example, it would almost be inevitable and highly convenient to assign a door in the initializer to a house and **DRY** up your code (Otherwise you would always have repeated lines of code). Other properties that are optional can then be assigned to the "empty classes" you mentioned.

Comment: that was very well written, thank you. Yes I was originally thinking that an empty object was without any methods. I'm glad i asked the question, all these answers have cleared up any misconceptions I was having.

Comment: @Umeed Glad to hear that! Often times, simple concepts are explained in a way that makes them seem very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Your website appears to be using the term "empty object" to mean one which is created *without* passing any additional data to the `init` or `new` method.

You ask are there any uses for such objects?

Absolutely!

Probably the two most common are:

```
[NSMutableArray new]
```

and:

```
[NSMutableDictionary new]
```

(or the equivalent `[[... alloc] init]`)

The above create new *empty* mutable array/dictionaries - a common requirement in programming.

HTH